# In objective-c is it possible to get the position of a regex match within the string

Tags: objective-c, regex, position, offset, nsregularexpression

If I have the string "Hello World", is it possible to use NSRegularExpression with the pattern @"World" to get the position of the match, i.e. in the "Hello World" example the position/index of the match should be "6"?

in php I'd use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with the "PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE" flag to achieve this, does objective-c support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it the Cocoa way:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"world" options:0 error:NULL];
// omitted error checking for the sake of simplicity
NSString *str = @"Hello world!";
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:str
    options:0
    range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)
    usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
    {
        NSLog(@"Match at [%d, %d]", result.range.location, result.range.length);
    }];
[regex release];
```

Or the POSIX way (this may be convenient for you, since you want only one match, and this function/method returns the match range directly):

```
#include <regex.h>

- (NSRange)matchString:(NSString *)string toRegex:(NSString *)regex
{
    regex_t regex_obj;
    regmatch_t match;
    const char *regex_str;
    const char *match_str;
    int error;

    regex_str = [regex UTF8String];
    error = regcomp(&regex_obj, regex_str, REG_EXTENDED);
    if (error)
    {
        return NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0);
    }

    match_str = [string UTF8String];
    error = regexec(&regex_obj, match_str, 1, &match, 0);
    if (error)
    {
        return NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0);
    }

    regfree(&regex_obj);
    return NSMakeRange(match.rm_so, match.rm_eo - match.rm_so);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat long in Cocoa, but you can do it:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"world"
    options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
    error:&error];
NSString *str = @"Hello, world!";
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:str
    options:0
    range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
if (match) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match range];
    NSLog(@"%lu", matchRange.location);
}
```

This prints `7`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to make a lot of use of RegEx's, I recommend looking at [RegexKit or RegexKitLite.](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Quite useless since the time Cocoa natively supports regular expressions (even on recent versions of iOS!)

Comment: @H2CO3 Not useless at all.  It's a nice framework with some nice features, like regex extensions to NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  You can use the NSRegularExpression method, rangeOfFirstMatchInString:options:range: which returns the range of the first match. You could also do this with the NSString method rangeOfString: if you don't need to use REGEX.